# I don't know what my credential storage password is. Can anybody help?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, password

I want to change the VPN on my Samsung Galaxy S but it keeps asking me for my credential storage password. Does anybody know how I get this?

Comment: It's been two and a half years. Is there still no answer to this for recent Android versions?

Comment: I know this is six years old, but the password (which I don't ever remember setting) ended up being the pin I used to have on the phone, if that ever helps anyone.

Answer (score 6):

Go to `Settings -> Location and security -> Credential storage -> Set password` to change it.

Comment: Do you know what the correlate for this is on recent Android versions? The menu items are not at all the same anymore.

Answer (score 2):

On recent versions of Android (since 4.3, at least) you have to set a password as your device unlock method. If you have a pin or pattern unlock configured, it seems that there is no way to access VPNs. Dumb, but it is what it is.

Just go to settings > security > screen lock, and choose password.

Comment: argh, this didn't work for me either. Any other ideas?